# Unterschied: "eine Welle" vs "eine Woge"?

Tags: meaning, difference, standard-german

Ich fand im Wörterbuch, dass sie das Gleiche bedeuten. Sind sie gleich oder gibt es Unterschiede in Benutzung und Anderem? Ich finde persönlich, dass "Welle" akustisch besser klingt, vielleicht ist "die Woge" altmodisch, und wird nie benutzt?

Comment: @Paul Frost: The DWDS usage database agrees for the most part, but it's also used in figurative expressions such as *Woge der Leidenschaften*. Also, I get flack all the time for answering in comments, but I guess it's ok if you do it German :)

Comment: Ich muss @RDBury bezüglich Mini-Antworten in Kommentarform zustimmen, bitte nochmal in [Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1696) nachlesen.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I will leave more time between commenting (as above) and actual deletion in the future, so one had a better chance of converting the comment to an answer oneself. My comment could also have mentioned pending deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Welle" ist das heute üblicherweise verwendete Wort, "Woge" ist eher im  Poetischen und in Idiomen zu finden. In Physik und Technik ist nur "Welle" üblich (z.B. elektromagnetische Welle, Schallwelle, stehende Welle).

Die Bedeutung ist auch nicht ganz dieselbe, eine Woge ist in der Tendenz größer und  entsprechend langsamer als eine Welle.

Es gibt auch das Verb "wogen", das eine Bewegung auf und ab oder hin und her  bezeichnet (siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wogen): "das wogende Meer", "Eine Menschenmenge wogte durch die Straßen"). Zu "Wellen" gibt es kein entsprechendes Verb.

Comment: Um den drei Beispielen für Physik noch eines für *Technik* zuzufügen: *Kurbelwelle*.

Answer (score 3):

Die Worte sind mehr oder weniger synonym. Allerdings wird *Woge* heutzutage möglicherweise nur noch in festen Wendungen wie

- die Wogen glätten
- auf einer Woge der Begeisterung/Sympathie

verwendet, und ist ansonsten eher poetisch. ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Woge) nennt die Verwendung "gehoben".)

Answer (score -3):

Eine Woge ist eine sanfte Welle, die das Schiff nur wiegt wie eine Wiege.

Comment: "Eine Woge ist eine sanfte Welle" ... nein, im Gegenteil ^^

Comment: @mtwde Stimmt, laut [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Woge) ist eine Woge eine große und starke Wasserwelle.

Comment: “Die Woge von Kanagawa” by Hokusai is probably the most famous Japanese woodcut. It’s not a gentle wave, it is total destruction.